# Datagrid expandable opens on all Datagrids on page

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

When having multiple `Datagrid` components on one page the expandable function gets confused and opens the record with the same `id` on all `Datagrids` on the page. See example on the tag list here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-s7cbum?file=src%2Ftags%2FTagList.tsx

Opening up the entry with `id = 1` opens up the record on both `Datagrid`s but for `id = 2 or 3` it works as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that's a current limitation of the framework.

Indeed the expanded keys are stored in the Store using this key: `${resource}.datagrid.expanded`, i.e. the state is shared for a given resource. ([source](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-core/src/controller/list/useExpanded.tsx#L26))

The only workaround I can think of is a dirty one: you can wrap your second `<Datagrid>` in a `<ResourceContextProvider>` to force using another resource. You might want to couple that with a Proxy around the `dataProvider` to map the API calls targeting this dummy resource to the correct one.

```
    <ResourceContextProvider value="test">
      <Datagrid
        data={[{ id: 1 }, { id: 4 }]}
        rowClick="expand"
        expand={<>Test</>}
        header={<>Header</>}
        prefix="test"
      >
        <TextField label="ID" source="id" />
      </Datagrid>
    </ResourceContextProvider>
```

[Fixed Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-s7cbum-vmchm6?file=src%2Ftags%2FTagList.tsx)

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I was afraid that `Datagrid` is using a shared state. However, it's no problem with the `dataProvider` in this case, as it's not a resource but I have multiple submodels in a resource which I show in their own `Datagrid` on the same page. Think of it as a cooking recipe resource with submodels "ingredients" and "steps" which I want to display. Obviously, it would be nicer to just have a prefix or something similar for the `Datagrid` to have their own state.